# How do I slice a pandas time series on dates not in the index?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, slice, series

I have a time series indexed by datetime.date. Here are the first knots of the series:

```
1999-12-31  0
2000-06-30  170382.118454
2000-12-29  -319260.443362
```

I want to slice from the beginning of the series until Dec 28th 2000, but this doesn't work since that date is not in the index (I get a KeyError when I try `original_series[:datetime.date(2000,12,28)]`. I've also tried converting the index to timestamps, but that gives very spurious results (it manufactures fake knots, see below), so I wondered if there's a good approach to this problem.

```
test = pd.Series(original_series.values, map(pd.Timestamp, original_series.index))
```

At a first glance, this looks alright:

```
1999-12-31         0.000000
2000-06-30    170382.118454
2000-12-29   -319260.443362
```

But then I try to do my slicing (where do those extra days in January 2000 come from?):

```
In [84]: test[:'2000-12-28']
Out[84]: 
1999-12-31         0.000000
2000-06-30    170382.118454
2000-01-03    -71073.979016
2000-01-04    100498.744748
2000-01-05     91104.743684
2000-01-06     82290.255459
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do, if `ts` is your `time.serie`:

```
In [77]: ts = pd.Series([99,65],index=pd.to_datetime(['2000-12-24','2000-12-30']))

In [78]: ts
Out[78]:
2000-12-24    99
2000-12-30    65
dtype: int64

In [79]: ts[ts.index<=pd.to_datetime('2000-12-28')]
Out[79]:
2000-12-24    99
dtype: int64
```

If you have `index` as `string` just proceed with:

```
ts[ts.index.map(pd.to_datetime)<=pd.to_datetime('2000-12-28')]
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right, but I was also being hilariously stupid - I hadn't sorted my time series by index, hence my confusion about the "manufactured" dates. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it without converting it into a time-series object.

Scenario when your index is not a date:

Your df: 
index   date     data 
0      2000-01-01  10 
1      2000-01-02  20 
2      2000-01-03  12

First, convert your date into date-time format:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

Second change index to date:

```
df = df.set_index("date")
```

Your df should now look like this:

**date**             data 
**2000-01-01**  10 
**2000-01-02**  20 
**2000-01-03**  12

Lastly, you can simply manipulate the rows by using:

```
df = df['2000-01-02':'2000-01-03']
```

Your df will now look like this:

**date**             data 
**2000-01-02**  20 
**2000-01-03**  12